# How can I reorder a javascript object based on the order of an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this array:

```
["fff-44-44", "1232-44-ddd", "aaa-222-333"]
```

I want to reorder this object:

```
Object { "fff-44-44": {…}, "aaa-222-333": {…}, "1232-44-ddd": {…} }
```

to this:

```
Object { "fff-44-44": {…}, "1232-44-ddd": {…}, "aaa-222-333": {…} }
```

Tried the following:

```
    var arr = Object.keys(this.state.products).map(function (key) { return this.state.products[key]; }.bind(this))

    arr.sort(function(a, b){  
      return this.props.orderArray.indexOf(a) - this.props.orderArray.indexOf(b);
    }.bind(this))
    let final = arr.reduce(function(o, val) { o[val] = val; return o; }, {});
```

It seems that the property of the object isn't converted into indexes, which a huge roadblock and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Order of keys inside object is not guaranteed.

Comment: Order is not guaranteed with objects.  You can't do it this way.  Instead, build a collection - an array of objects: `[{id: 'fff-44-44', ...}, {id: 'aaa-22-333', ...}, ...]`

Comment: Objects don't have a guaranteed order - don't rely on it.

Comment: Can't be done with any certainty. The question is, why do you want/need this?

Comment: As other have implied or stated, there are definitely ways around your current issue. Think about your code differently.